# If $p$ and $q$ are coprime positive integers s.t. $\frac{p}{q}=\sum_{k=0}^{100}\frac1{3^{2^k}+1}$, what is the smallest prime factor of $p$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, summation, fractions, prime-factorization

> If the sum $$S=\frac14+\frac1{10}+\frac1{82}+\frac1{6562}+\cdots+\frac1{3^{2^{100}}+1}$$
> is expressed in the form $\frac pq,$ where $p,q\in\mathbb N$ and $\gcd(p, q) =1.$ Then what is smallest prime factor of $p$ ?

We have: $$S=\sum_{k=0}^{100} \frac1{3^{2^k}+1}.$$ Please give me some hints to evaluate such kind of sums, in general.

**Remark.**

- Since $4$ divides the denominator of the zeroth term ($\frac14$) of $S$, but does not divide the denominator of any other term, we can see that $2\nmid p$.
- Note that each term of $S$ is $\equiv 1\pmod{3}$.  Therefore, $S\equiv 101\cdot 1\equiv 2\pmod{3}$, so $3\nmid p$.
- Since $5$ divides the denominator of the first term ($\frac1{10}$) of $S$, but not the denominator of any other term, we conclude that $5\nmid p$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @Integrand, Sir I have just started to deal with sequences and series few months back, as our course structure has introduced us with the basics Real analysis in this semester and I quite love this topic, so in this lockdown period I decided to practice and solve various kind of problems regarding sequences, series, Riemann integration... There is a local math magazine which provides problems related to real analysis, number theory etc etc. I have taken this question from that magazine. But I really don't know how to start with it. So I asked for some hints. Confession: I haven't started...

Comment: ...number theory yet. So I guess I won't be able to tackle this question yet. I will mark this question and try to solve it after acquiring some knowledge on elementary number theory..

Comment: Perhaps, the only way is via bruteforcing.  For example, observe that $3^{2^k}$ modulo $7$ for $k=0,1,2,\ldots$ are
$$3,2,4,2,4,2,4,\ldots\,.$$  That is, $\dfrac{1}{3^{2^k}+1}$ modulo $7$ for $k=0,1,2,\ldots$ are
$$2,5,3,5,3,5,3,\ldots\,.$$
That is, $S$ modulo $7$ is
$$2+5\cdot 50+3\cdot 50=402\equiv 3\pmod{7}\,.$$  Then, you try this with other primes.

Comment: Following my comment above, we know that if a prime natural number $r$ divides $p$, then $r>7$.  We now try $r=11$.  The sequence $3^{2^k}$ modulo $11$ for $k=0,1,2,3,\ldots$ is
$$3,9,4,5,3,9,4,5,3,9,4,5,\ldots\,.$$
Therefore, $\dfrac{1}{3^{2^k}+1}$ for $k=0,1,2,3,\ldots$ are
$$3,10,9,2,3,10,9,2,3,10,9,2,\ldots\,.$$
Consequently, $$S\equiv 3+(10+9+2+3)\cdot 25=603\equiv 9 \pmod{11}\,.$$
Therefore, $r>11$ as well.  There are only seven primes $13$, $17$, $19$, $23$, $29$, $31$, and $37$ left to check.

Comment: @Batominovski, thank so much sir. Though I haven't understand all the things, you've written. Need to Google few things. I actually thought that this question is actually about evaluating the sum via some trick related to real analysis and then we would get a result which is a fraction. And I can easily find the required smallest prime factor. But it turns out that it is based on number theory. But thank you so much sir for all the things: edits, comments....

Comment: Now, it is easy to see that $$S\equiv 10+(4+10)\cdot 50=710\equiv 8\pmod{13}\,.$$
Thus, $r>13$.  Also, $17$ divides the denominator of the third term $\dfrac{1}{3^{2^3}+1}$ of $S$, but not the denominator of any other terms.  Therefore, $r>17$.

Comment: Next,
$$\begin{align}S&\equiv 5+(2+16+11+18+4+9)\cdot16+(2+16+11+18)\\&=1012\equiv 5\pmod{19}\,,\end{align}$$
$$\begin{align}S&\equiv 6+(7+ 16+10+ 5+ 18+ 17+ 8+ 14+ 19+ 6)\cdot10\\&=1206\equiv 10\pmod{23}\,,\end{align}$$
$$\begin{align}S\equiv 22+3+ (23+11+ 18)\cdot 33=1741 \equiv 1\pmod{29}\,,\end{align}$$
and
$$S\equiv 8+(28+14+3+15)\cdot 25=1533\equiv 14\pmod{31}\,.$$
Ergo, $r>31$.

Comment: Finally, 
$$\begin{align}S&\equiv 28+(26+14+ 20+ 12+ 24+ 18)\cdot 16+26+14+20+12\\&=1924\equiv 0\pmod{37}\,.\end{align}$$
Therefore, $r=37$ is the smallest prime natural number that divides $p$.  I think you can accept [WhatsUp's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3766710/72152) now.  If you are curious how I obtained the numbers above, play around with [this WolframAlpha query](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Table%5BPowerMod%5B3%5E%282%5Ek%29%2B1%2C-1%2C37%5D%2C%7Bk%2C0%2C20%7D%5D).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what kind of problem this is.

It seems that the problem is not intended to be done by hand.

If we denote by $S(n)$ the number $\displaystyle\sum_{k = 0}^n \frac 1{3^{2^k} + 1}$, then the first several values of the numerator of $S(n)$ look like this:

```
1
7
3^3 * 11
974867
20982415713197
3 * 6480139987906036648979676749
13 * 25220504737903 * 1202418613506277 * 84660948985522106511557529679
149 * 883 * 126001 * 11868766710884224982021663692780373317124689104200960317897970407656906279023556512105818421377935790975902821
```

Of course, it is easy to show that $3$ divides the numerator if $n \equiv 2 \pmod 3$. This would be a much more reasonable exercise in elementary number theory.

However we have here $n = 100$. This leads to something without a pattern.

With the help of some computer algebra system, I am able to find that the smallest prime factor of the numerator is $37$. This is done by checking all primes up to $37$ one by one. So it is not really doable with paper and pencil.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I too fail to see the point of this question, especially without context.

Comment: @Whatsup, thank you sir for your answer. Found this question on a local magazine. If everything remains alright, then they will publish the answers to the various problems, next month.

Comment: OK, perhaps you can share the answer with us next month!

Comment: Sure sir. If they publish the respective answer, I'll update here. (I have observed that sometimes they don't publish some answers, it might be that they couldn't find an answer) Hopefully they'll publish the answer to this question.